# Angular Project with Docker -- Client App not copying

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, dockerfile, .net-6.0

So I'm admittedly new to Docker, and containerization in general. But I am having a problem--my docker image is not saving my Client App file, my angular file, at all. I believe this because on my docker desktop, the file size is 208.59 mbs, which is only a mb (and some change) bigger than the base image I am using (mcr.micrsofot.com/dontet/aspnet:6.0). I could be completely wrong here, but I cannot find my client app when I run the image in a container, and it only loads the default tutorial.

To Build...

```
docker build -t containerName .
```

To Run...

```
docker run -tdp 443:3000 containerName
```

Then I would open localhost:3000 and it gives me an error saying it cannot load the page. There are no problems in the build process, and my Dockerfile is as follows...

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

ENV NODE_VERSION=16.13.0
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
ENV NVM_DIR=/root/.nvm
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm install ${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm use v${NODE_VERSION}
RUN . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" && nvm alias default v${NODE_VERSION}
ENV PATH="/root/.nvm/versions/node/v${NODE_VERSION}/bin/:${PATH}"
RUN node --version
RUN npm --version

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["projectName.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./projectName.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."

RUN dotnet build "projectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "projectName.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projectName.dll"]
```

I created the dockerfile using the add -> dockersupport function off of Visual Studio, and then added this section to install NodeJs, NVM and NPM.
I thought maybe it was something in the csproj file, so I will include that as well. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling dockerDesktop, I have tried building with this Dockerfile more than once, and I have ran ng build --prod to create the dist file, although I am aware that the csproj file does that for me.
csproj file ...

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
    <SpaProxyServerUrl>https://localhost:44401</SpaProxyServerUrl>
    <SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <UserSecretsId>alot of letters and numbers</UserSecretsId>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileContext>.</DockerfileContext>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy" Version="6.0.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <!-- Don't publish the SPA source files, but do show them in the project files list -->
    <Content Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Remove="$(SpaRoot)**" />
    <None Include="$(SpaRoot)**" Exclude="$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
  </Target>
  
  <Target Name="PublishRunWebpack" AfterTargets="ComputeFilesToPublish">
    <!-- As part of publishing, ensure the JS resources are freshly built in production mode -->
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build -- --prod" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="$(SpaRoot)dist\**; $(SpaRoot)dist-server\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>wwwroot\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        <ExcludeFromSingleFile>true</ExcludeFromSingleFile>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I also thought maybe the fact that my client app is not in the wwwroot folder could be a problem, but I believe that things in the wwwroot are only for live versions of the site, and I am simply trying to create an image that has my site on it. Any help/resources is much appreciated.

Comment: I solved it, not sure what the actual problem was, but uninstalling and reinstalling docker did the trick. my image data saved and displayed in the appropriate port. For anyone trying to solve this in the future, I tried all of the following: Rerunning docker cmd with --no-cache , rebuilding using a different port, exposing different ports, deleting the image and rebuilding with the same port, etc. Even when I deleted docker the localhost:80 terminal was still displaying the docker tutorial--which I thought was incredibly strange. However, uninstalling and reinstalling docker seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling and reinstalling docker did the trick. I realized after the first uninstall that localhost:80 was still loading the tutorial page, so I've come to the conclusion that it was just a weird bug--regardless, the issue was resolved after uninstalling and reinstalling docker, and rebuilding/rerunning the image. I did not change the dockerfile commands, and I did not change the csproj file, simply uninstalled, reinstalled, and ran the following commands

```
docker build -t myimageName .
```

and then for the run

```
docker run -dp 80:80/tcp myimageName:latest
```